# How to properly load data files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py, data-files

So.. I have this little problem with my program. I might need to have some basic stuff explained - especially what happens when stuff is installed via distutils.

I have two icons that I'm using in my GUI application made in Tkinter. I have a problem with loading them because of their location.

You can see my `setup.py` file [here](https://github.com/comatory/flashCardStudy/blob/master/setup.py). You can see my specified files on line 28 (they reside in subfolder `gui/`).

Of course the problem starts when you want to run GUI portion of the program (that can be done by installing it and run it as `flashstudy --gui` executable). I get error in file `main.py` on line 44 & 45 (the file is [here](https://github.com/comatory/flashCardStudy/blob/master/gui/main.py)). The images cannot be loaded from the location.

I guess it makes sense because it's supposed to look to the directory where the files were transferred during installation but I don't know where that place is and how to load it easily.

Another thing - the reason why it is set up that way is so you can run the program and GUI portion directly from terminal without installing it, I'd like to keep that functionality.

Is there a way to do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) rather than `distutils`, you can reliably include data files and load them again after installation, regardless of how the data files were installed.

You already import `setuptools` but are ignoring it otherwise; rather than import `setup` from `distutils.core`, import it from `setuptools`:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Use the `package_data` or `include_package_data`, rather than the `data_files` option to include your images. See [*Including Data Files*](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) in the `setuptools` documentation:

```
package_data = {'gui': ['*.gif']}
```

You can then load your package data with the [`pkg_resources` *Resource API*](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api). For TKinter `PhotoImage` objects you need a filename, so you could use:

```
icon_up = PhotoImage(
    file=pkg_resources.resource_filename('flashCardStudy', 'gui/up.gif'))
```

Personally, I'd embed a base64 data string in the source instead, and use that as the icon:

```
icon_up_data = '''\
    R0lGODlhEAAQAJEAAAAAAP///////wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQABAAAAIflI+pywfQ0ovuQWpv
    y3PzyHVKKErkQlpjqhmsSsVRAQA7
'''
icon_up = PhotoImage(data=icon_up_data)
```

This bypasses the whole issue altogether. Note that this only works for GIF images however.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to correct resources. For some reason I had some issues with `setuptools` before when used with PIP, I don't quite remember and when I switched to `distutils` I got rid of the issue. Anyway I'm going to try `setuptools` again to see if it's gotten better.

I looked at it and yes, using base64 data is the simplest so I went with it. I'm only using these two images anyway so it's probably not worth importing the files.